# Starting from the script scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, entry-point

Good day!
Show you how to run the script from scrapy, which is located in the root directory of the project, if the spider folder is located somewhere else.
I did not understand either manual, or there is only description of the startup script spider spiders.

[image]

Sorry, the English I do bad, so can something not understood.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Please explain what you want to do, what you tried, what you got as result, what you expected instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to run from the Python-script spiders. Then I still knew little about Python and Scrapy.
The issue is now resolved. You either use Scrapy API, or spiders run by means of the operating system commands via a Python script.
Once again I apologize for my "English".